# Convert Image from GIF To JPEG

Tags: c#, jpeg

I had to convert GIF to JPEG. I had to save the bytes to image then reopen it and convert it to JPEG. I tried to change the type using two streams but I got error "A generic error occurred in GDI+". Is there any explanation for this?

```
    public static byte[] GetJpegBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            var temporaryImage = $"{Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())}.jpeg";
            var image = Image.FromStream(stream);

            image.Save(temporaryImage, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            using (var memoryStream = new FileStream(temporaryImage, FileMode.Open))
            {
                byte[] byteRsult = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
                memoryStream.Read(byteRsult, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
                memoryStream.Close();
                File.Delete(temporaryImage);
                return byteRsult;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF

Comment: can you put FileAccess.Read in "using (var memoryStream = new FileStream(temporaryImage, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))"

Comment: I was able and I am able, it was a mistake ;)

Comment: Where do you get this GDI error? When reading the stream in `Image.FromStream`, or when writing as jpeg in `image.Save`? Are you sure, the inputstream is a valid gif-image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension for convert format image
I use this simple extension to convert a stream.

```
public static Stream ConvertImage(this Stream originalStream, ImageFormat format)
{
          var image = Image.FromStream(originalStream);

               using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
           {
                image.Save(stream, format);
                stream.Position = 0;
                return stream;
           }
    }
```

**usage:**

```
var outputStream = stream.ConvertImage(ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use stream you can try this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("C:\MyFile.jpg");

bitmap.Save("C:\MyNewFile.gif", ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Comment: ... or the other way round "From GIF to JPEG" as the title says ;-)

Comment: @gofal3 yes off course, just to change the filename